How to use different images for big and small screens using sw_thumbnails
I want to use a wide image (landscape) for laptop screen, but for mobile I want to use an entirely different image which will be tall (portrait).
How can i achieve it using sw_thumbnails?
I've created a custom field which I assigned to category

now somehow i want to use it to display banner images on my storefront
The path for this file is storefront/Resources/views/storefront/element/cms-element-image.html.twig
{% sw_thumbnails 'cms-image-thumbnails' with {
    media: element.data.media,
} %}

I've already looked at the documentation, but this only addresses using the same image, but in another size.

https://developer.shopware.com/docs/guides/plugins/plugins/storefront/use-media-thumbnails.html

i have read the documentation i think eveywhere in the documentation they are using a  single image with muitiple sizes i want mutiple images for mutiple sizes

somethinh like a picutre tag of html functionality

As there is no response yet for this question: Keep in mind you could also extend twig and create another function that could solve this for you
